# My D810 is saving NEF rather than jpgs on secondary slot

Tags: raw, backup, nikon-d810

I have set the secondary slot to save a JPG version of each shot. But it is in fact saving a NEF version instead. This would be correct if set as backup, but it's not, I have checked more than a couple of times.

Comment: Do you have the camera set up to store both NEFs and JPGs? I wonder if it defaults to NEF backup mode if you aren't set up for taking/processing/saving both under the 'Quality' menu (Qual button).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your camera is only recording RAW images. You need to set the image quality setting to one of the RAW+JPEG options:

- NEF (RAW) + JPEG fine
- NEF (RAW) + JPEG normal
- NEF (RAW) + JPEG basic

Once you have chosen one of those modes, the camera will store `.NEF` files to one card, and `.JPG` files to the other card.

See the section titled **Image Quality** on pages 79–80 in the [D810 User Manual](https://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/Uslma00vmWju01F4NIw08vXsPQ61/D810FM_DL(En)01.pdf).